# How to copy .war to Tomcat's webapps directory using Maven?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

Is there anything I can add to `pom.xml` that will copy the generated `.war` file from the `target` directory to my Tomcat's `webapps` directory?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I used the Maven WAR Plugin:
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html

Comment: The code to add is :  <outputDirectory></outputDirectory> in the configuration tag of the maven-war-plugin artifactId

Comment: How could one do this in the case where the webapps folder is on a remote server (e.g. could it copy over SCP?). I'm trying to do this with the maven-wagon-ssh library, and it almost works, but I can't figure out how to control which files are sent and where they go.

Answer (score 74):

```
<build>
   <plugins>
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <configuration>
           <outputDirectory><!-- Tomcat webapps location--></outputDirectory>
           <!-- Example of Tomcat webapps location :D:\tomcat\webapps\ -->
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Once you have added it to your `pom.xml`, you can copy the WAR file by calling `mvn package` or `mvn war:war`.

Comment: Thanks :) this works. OP should mark it as verified answer.

Answer (score 9):

This is the correct approach :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <warName>${name}</warName>
        <outputDirectory>C:\Tomcat7\webapps</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This will put a war file in C:\Tomcat7\webapps folder with the name of the maven project.

Comment: No, it is not. This is very hacky way.

Answer (score 7):

You can use http://cargo.codehaus.org/Deploying+to+a+running+container and configure it accordingly.

Comment: Deploying to one is easy! :) Deploying to two is hard. :( (unless you run the deploy command twice) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/732275/maven-deploy-to-multiple-tomcat-servers

Comment: @valerio, link is broken its not opening

Answer (score 6):

You could also have a look at the jetty plugin. Just type "mvn jetty:run-war" and jetty should run your war-file.

Edit: Jetty is a light weight servlet container suitable for development and testing. It's also lightning fast to start.

Comment: I don't want to run the war file.  I want it placed in tomcat's webapps directory rather than having to do it manually.

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, you could have tomcat look in your target directory and deploy directly from there.

In your context.xml or server.xml's Context element:

```
<Context path="" docBase="/path/to/target/exploded">
...
</Context>
```

Then you can use the war:exploded goal to create your exploded war.

Comment: Can you give more information on how this is setup.  I've done this in the past but google is having trouble locating example configurations.

Comment: Upranking this answer.  Although many of the other ways work, this was by far the fastest for me (1.5min build vs 7min with the next fastest approach)

Answer (score 3):

Not ideal, but if you have a really strange app server setup, you could always use an antrun task set to execute when the packaging is run

```
      <build>
        ....
        <plugins>
           <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
              <executions>
                <execution>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <configuration>
                    <tasks>
                      <!-- Ant copy tasks go here -->
                    </tasks>
                  </configuration>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>run</goal>
                  </goals>
                </execution>
              </executions>
            </plugin>
         </plugins>
      </build>
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the above answers.

The below answer works for me. This is just a consolidated one. Nothing special!

```
</project>
 ........ 
   <build>
    <finalName>HelloWorld1</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-8.5.8\webapps\</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

> For more information. Please refer to [dependency:copy](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html) official
>   page for more information.

Comment: Caveat - this technique does not create the war file in the `<project>/target` directory then copy it into the `outputDirectory`.  This builds it directly in the `outputDirectory`.  So if you are expecting a copy of the war file in the `target` directory, it will not be there.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with the [dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html)