# How to disable node from tomcat cluster using ant script?

Tags: tomcat, deployment, ant, cluster-computing

I would like to write an **ant script to deploy application on the Tomcat cluster**. My deploy strategy looks exacly the same like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766520)

Let say that I have a cluster with 4 Tomcat nodes.

The deploy strategy steps:

1. Disable monitoring of single node
2. Pull that node out of cluster
3. Deploy new code to it
4. Verify node is operating properly with new code
5. Put node back into cluster
6. Re-enable monitoring for that node
7. Repeat steps for every other node

I would like to know, how can I disable tomcat cluster node for the deployment of the new application? I think its not possible to make a deployment on all nodes at the same time without disturbing my users. Is there any good way to do this?

Would be great if somebody could help me with it.

Comment: ANT is a build tool. I feel it's the wrong solution for managing your application's run-time environment. Have you considered CM tooling like Chef or Puppet?

Answer (score 0):

You may use Mod_cluster for load balancing to a cluster of Tomcat nodes. With Mod_cluster it is possible to disable/enable single nodes, groups of nodes (load balancing groups) and particular contexts, thus performing rolling updates etc. HTH