# Deploying maven project into an existing Tomcat server

Tags: maven, tomcat, deployment, pom.xml

Currently my project setup is such that when I do a clean and install on my maven project, it downloads tomcat version mentioned in the pom.xml and deploys the war files onto it.

I need to change the configuration such that the war files are deployed on to tomcat which I have manually downloaded and not the one maven downloads. This is to make use of the settings I have configured for the manually downloaded tomcat.

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369639/mvn-copy-war-to-webapps.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the [tomcat-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/deployment.html) which lets you deploy by context.xml, exploded war or simply war file into existing tomcat instances.

Answer (score 1):

I know you'd probably want a `Maven`-only answer to this - I did too. However, I found that the easiest but most flexible thing to do was to build the war with Maven, and deploy it with `ANT`. The tomcat-maven-plugin wasn't powerful enough for me because I needed to deploy the .war to a local `Tomcat` install AND to a remote machine using `scp`.

Here's what my `ANT` `build.xml` file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
<target name="deploy_local">
    <echo>Deploying .war to local Tomcat</echo>
    <copy file="target/My.war" todir="/tomcat/webapps">
    </copy>
</target>

<target name="deploy_production">
    <echo>Deploying .war to production Tomcat</echo>
    <move file="target/My.war" tofile="target/ROOT.war"/>
    <scp file="target/ROOT.war"
        trust="true"
        todir="me:password@154.14.232.122:/tomcat/webapps"
        port="22">
    </scp>
</target>
```

You can see I even rename the .war file from My.war to ROOT.war for the production deploy.

The complete procedure is then: `mvn clean package` followed by running the local or production `ANT` target for deployment.