# Uploading WAR project to Tomcat using Maven without providing the "manager app"

Tags: maven, tomcat, deployment

#### Cargo Problem

Using Maven, uploading to server seems to be done via **Cargo plugin** or the "**Tomcat plugin**". But as it seems they use the Tomcat **manager application** to upload to the server:

- This link: [Maven: copy WAR to Tomcat's webapps directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369639/mvn-copy-war-to-webapps), does not provide a way to upload, It's about copying (locally) the package. **I don't want to copy locally. Want to upload to remote server.**
- This one: [Deploying maven project into an existing Tomcat server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454215/deploying-maven-project-into-an-existing-tomcat-server?lq=1), suggests Tomcat plugin. But **I don't want to be dependent on manager application access**.

#### Just Want Uploading The File

Any way I just want to have something like: simply providing FTP of SFTP access to the target folder (usually $CATALINA_HOME/webapp) for the plugin and it just uploads the war file to the target. No manager access, nothing like that. The rest is taken of by *autodeploy* in Tomcat.

So, what is the solution?

P.S. `mvn delpoy` does not seem to be a solution, since it says it's for "repositories" not runtime.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven copy local file to remote server using SSH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909867/maven-copy-local-file-to-remote-server-using-ssh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either the [`maven-exec-plugin`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) to execute any shell script doing the `scp`.

Another solution, if you are familiar with ant is to use the [`maven-antrun-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) and having an ant task doing the scp

helpful links :

- [exec-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491937/i-want-to-execute-shell-commands-from-mavens-pom-xml)
- [antrun-plugin + scp](http://maksim.sorokin.dk/it/2010/08/26/copy-files-with-scp-using-maven/)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the _maven-exec-plugin_. Yes that is possible, but I was looking for a more "specialized" solution. To me, using the "exec" here seems like more of a workaround, rather than the specific solution.

If no better answers are proposed in a reasonable time, I will accept this. Thank you.