# How to deploy WAR with Maven to Tomcat?

Tags: maven, tomcat

I use the Maven with Eclipse. Is possible build the project and then deploy built WAR file to Tomcat server?

I use Windows. I can build `WAR` file, and also deploy it on the server manually. But I want to deploy the `WAR` file automatically after build action and it doesn't work. I am novice in Maven.

Should I set something in my run configuration? I have set goals to `install` value.

*pom.xml*

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>HelloWorld</groupId>
<artifactId>HelloWorld</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>HelloWorld</name>

<properties>
    <spring.version>3.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Java Server Pages Standard Tag Library -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java-version}</source>
                <target>${java-version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sources</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Maven Tomcat Plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <server>Apache_Tomcat_7_x86</server>
                <warFile>${project.build.directory}/HelloWorld-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war</warFile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/web.xml</packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Furthermore I changed `settings.xml` file in path `~/.m2/settings.xml`.

*settings.xml*

```
  <servers>
      <server>
        <id>Apache_Tomcat_7_x86</id>
        <username>admin</username>
        <password>admin</password>
      </server>
  </servers>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369639/maven-copy-war-to-tomcats-webapps-directory

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Meanwhile I resolved it. There were a few issues.

Firstly I set **Goal** in the Eclipse **run configuration** to `tomcat:deploy`.

And I changed `pom.xml` following

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
    <server>Apache_Tomcat_7_x86</server>
    <path>/HelloWorld</path>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

URL in configuration depends on Tomcat version. For me works `text`, for others works `html` on end of URL. And of course, in `tomcat-users.xml` must be set role `manager-script` or `manager-gui`.

Maybe it helps to others.

Comment: more details [here](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-deploy-maven-based-war-file-to-tomcat/)