# Deploy war to local Tomcat instance not managed by netbeans

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, web-deployment

I need to deploy my webapp to a non-managed Tomcat outside of NetBeans. Is there any way to do that using NetBeans? My NetBeans 7.4 came with Tomcat 7.0.41, but my Ubuntu 12.04 has got Tomcat 7.0.26 outside of NetBeans. I want deploy war to Tomcat 7.0.26. Because Tomcat 7.0.26 has a directory structure that is different from the one expected by NetBeans, I can't add Tomcat 7.0.26 to Netbeans.

How can I deploy (and hot deploy) to Tomcat unmanaged by NetBeans ?

Comment: Could you explain how the directory structures differs?

Comment: Here's the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369639/maven-copy-war-to-tomcats-webapps-directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how could I deploy(& hot deploy) to Tomcat unmanaged by netbeans ?

You might modify the `build.xml` in your Netbeans project: before deploying add an `Ant` target that copies your `war` and `context.xml` to your Tomcat not managed by Netbeans.