# Cannot use "Deploy to container plugin" in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, tomcat8

I want to deploy a java maven webapp to a local tomcat8 via jenkins. I found out that I need to install the "Deploy to container plugin", which I did.

I figured, now I should be able to add a post-build action in the configuration of my pipeline. (like described here: [Deploy webapp to Tomcat after Maven build on Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45662176/deploy-webapp-to-tomcat-after-maven-build-on-jenkins))

But under "configure" of my pipeline there is no tab that says "post build action" (I also don't have the build tab, which I saw on a few screenshots). After researching I added a bunch of plugins described in a few tutorials, like "Hudson Post build task" and "PostBuildScript Plugin" but that didn't change anything.

Am I missing a specific plugin or is there something else wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a job of 'Pipeline' type (not a 'Freestyle' type where those 'PostBuildScript plugin' refers to), you need the perform the above in the 'post' part of your pipeline:

```
pipeline {
  agent
  ...
  stages {
    ...
  }
  post {
    PUT YOUR CODE HERE!!!
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah yes I also figured that out. But still thanks! so this means that if I choose the "pipeline" type, I can only add post build actions in the Jenkinsfile itself, is that correct?